# Hive static partition loading all the records

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to perform hive static partition based on dept of employee records, when I execute load command to insert data into my partitioned table ,it is changing all the dept value based on my partition value which I specify in load data command.

My data in hdfs looks like:

```
1,adi,Admin,50000,A
2,Gokul,Admin,50000,B
3,Janet,Sales,60000,A
4,Hari,Admin,50000,C
5,Sanker,Admin,50000,C
6,Margaret,Tech,12000,A
7,Nirmal,Tech,12000,B
8,jinju,Engineer,45000,B
9,Nancy,Admin,50000,A
10,Andrew,Manager,40000,A
11,Arun,Manager,40000,B
12,Harish,Sales,60000,B
13,Robert,Manager,40000,A
14,Laura,Engineer,45000,A
15,Anju,Ceo,100000,B
16,Aarathi,Manager,40000,B
17,Parvathy,Engineer,45000,B
18,Gopika,Admin,50000,B
19,Steven,Engineer,45000,A
20,Michael,Ceo,100000,A
```

My partitioned table is shown below:

```
create table employee(
id string,
name string,
role string,
salary string)
partitioned by (dept string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile;

load command
load data inpath '/user/adithyan/employee.txt' overwrite into table employee partition (dept='A');
```

I have given the input data above and after executed this command record has been inserted from hdfs to hive but it loaded all the records of the dept changed by 'A'

**Output :**

```
employee.id employee.name   employee.degree employee.salary employee.dept
1   adi Admin   50000   A
2   Gokul   Admin   50000   A
3   Janet   Sales   60000   A
4   Hari    Admin   50000   A
5   Sanker  Admin   50000   A
6   Margaret    Tech    12000   A
7   Nirmal  Tech    12000   A
8   jinju   Engineer    45000   A
9   Nancy   Admin   50000   A
10  Andrew  Manager 40000   A
11  Arun    Manager 40000   A
12  Harish  Sales   60000   A
13  Robert  Manager 40000   A
14  Laura   Engineer    45000   A
15  Anju    Ceo 100000  A
16  Aarathi Manager 40000   A
17  Parvathy    Engineer    45000   A
18  Gopika  Admin   50000   A
19  Steven  Engineer    45000   A
20  Michael Ceo 100000  A
```

All the dept has been changed to A which is wrong.
Can somebody help me on how to insert partition data into my table?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the **load data** is not fit for the job.

> Load operations are currently pure copy/move operations that move
>   datafiles into locations corresponding to Hive tables.
>
> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Loadingfilesintotables

However, you can achieve your goal using external table.

```
create external table employee_ext
(
    id      string
   ,name    string
   ,role    string
   ,salary  string
   ,dept    string
)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile
location '/user/adithyan/'
;
```

---

```
insert into employee partition (dept) select * from employee_ext;
```

---

```
select * from employee
;
```

---

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
| employee.id | employee.name | employee.role | employee.salary | employee.dept |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
|           1 | adi           | Admin         |           50000 | A             |
|           3 | Janet         | Sales         |           60000 | A             |
|           6 | Margaret      | Tech          |           12000 | A             |
|           9 | Nancy         | Admin         |           50000 | A             |
|          10 | Andrew        | Manager       |           40000 | A             |
|          13 | Robert        | Manager       |           40000 | A             |
|          14 | Laura         | Engineer      |           45000 | A             |
|          19 | Steven        | Engineer      |           45000 | A             |
|          20 | Michael       | Ceo           |          100000 | A             |
|           2 | Gokul         | Admin         |           50000 | B             |
|           7 | Nirmal        | Tech          |           12000 | B             |
|           8 | jinju         | Engineer      |           45000 | B             |
|          11 | Arun          | Manager       |           40000 | B             |
|          12 | Harish        | Sales         |           60000 | B             |
|          15 | Anju          | Ceo           |          100000 | B             |
|          16 | Aarathi       | Manager       |           40000 | B             |
|          17 | Parvathy      | Engineer      |           45000 | B             |
|          18 | Gopika        | Admin         |           50000 | B             |
|           4 | Hari          | Admin         |           50000 | C             |
|           5 | Sanker        | Admin         |           50000 | C             |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
```